# Retrieving Data with Datasnapshot - Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am able to save data into my firebase data. My issue is with the retrieving of the data into the recyclerView. I have realized that when I save new data, the snapshot reloads the recyclerView with all data once again instead of just updating the newly added data.

Let say I have Bill and Gate already in my database and showing up on my recyclerView. When I add Mark, the recycler view will then be populated in this manner. Bill, Gate, Bill, Gate, Mark.

When I navigate to another activity and return, it displays it rightly like Bill, Gate, Mark. My question is why the duplicate after a new entry? Is that the nature of Data snapshot?

```
public void OnDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot)
        {
            var items = snapshot.Child(mAuth.CurrentUser.Uid)?.Children?.ToEnumerable<DataSnapshot>();
            HashMap map;
            foreach (DataSnapshot item in items)
            {

                map = (HashMap)item.Value;
                peace_Hero.Add(new Hero(map.Get("Name")?.ToString()));
            }

            Adapter adapter = new Adapter(Hero,this);
            rv.SetLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            rv.SetItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            rv.SetAdapter(refreshAdapter);

            refreshAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
            refreshAdapter.ItemClick += OnItemClick;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo to reproduce this problem?

Comment: I have found a solution to it. I basically wasn't clearing my listview after every update